# Anyone can do a Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, knowledge

I went through a random word generator until I found a nice one to make a Riley out of:

My Prefix can crunch, wash, or rock.
And can be found prominent, on those who aren't scared.

My Infix grows the prettiest flowers.
But without it, the world will surely be a solemnly bared.

My Suffix strums a sweet melody.
And looks like a fruit, that won't want to be shared.

My whole refuses to be a pessimist.

I tried not to make this too tricky as it's my first post, will give hints as appropriate.

**EDIT**

> Added an extra line to each section to make it a bit easier (and rhyme).

Comment: Wow, did u really use a word generator lol :D

Comment: @KevinL to find the overall word, yes. literally randomwordgenerator dot com. The riddle itself is all my creation.

Comment: Lol I'll try using that generator in my next riddle probably XD

Comment: @KevinL hahah, me too! Saves me the struggle of coming up with a word :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's

> ABSOLUTE

My Prefix can crunch, wash, or rock.
And can be found prominent, on those who aren't scared.

> ABS (crunches, washboard abs, rock hard abs)

My Infix grows the prettiest flowers.
But without it, the world will surely be a solemnly bared.

> SOL (the sun)

My Suffix strums a sweet melody.
And looks like a fruit, that won't want to be shared.

> Lute (pear-shaped strummed instrument)

Comment: Hot damn you got it. Well done! What did you think of it? Also any ideas on the reasoning from the "whole" clue?

Comment: @AHKieran It was a fun one.  Is the whole a reference to absolute value being nonnegative?

Comment: yes! Well done I'm so glad you got it.